# Is there a getInt function on Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io

I would like to have a `getInt :: IO Int` function on Haskell. It would be a function that would take an integer from **stdin**, leaving the rest of the buffer intact.

The library function with this type I have found, `readLn :: IO Int`, for example, would not work with an input like:

```
2
3 4
```

Because it would take the entire line `3 4`, instead of taking `3` and leaving `4` for the next `getInt`. Although I know I could read the complete string and then split it using `words`, I would like to ask if there is a way which does not consume the buffer.

Is there any function on the standard libraries doing this? Is there any simple/obvious way to create a `getInt` I am missing?

Comment: Are you okay with your function consuming the separator between `Int`s? If so, it seems straightforward to cook up a loop that calls `getChar` until you see a separator, then call `readIO` on the resulting `String`.

Comment: Maybe it would work changing a '\n' for a ' ' or something similar in the `getLine` implementation (?) http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Text.html#hGetLine

Comment: That is essentially what I described, yes, though to begin with I would suggest skipping all the buffering-aware fanciness of the standard `getLine` implementation.

Comment: Oh, great, I have not seen that comment. I think it will work perfectly. Thanks, Daniel Wagner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I turn my comment into an answer, since it seems the original asker is okay with consuming separators. First we will define a `getWord` analog to `getLine`; then we will `readIO` the result. We will be careful to catch EOF exceptions in case they occur.

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char
import System.IO.Error

getWord :: IO String
getWord = handle handleEOF $ do
  c <- getChar
  if isSpace c then return [] else (c:) <$> getWord
  where
  handleEOF e = if isEOFError e then return [] else throwIO e

readWord :: Read a => IO a
readWord = getWord >>= readIO
```

Beware: this will of course not work well for values to be read that have a space in them (like `Data.Map`s or other complex data types).

Comment: What happens if you encounter EOF? To do this robustly I think you need to use `hLookAhead`.

Comment: @ErikR I have updated `getWord` to handle EOF gracefully.

Comment: Why not use `handleJust :: Exception e => (e -> Maybe b) -> (b -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a` with `handleJust (guard . isEOFError) (\() -> return []) $ do ...`?

Comment: @dfeuer Why is that better? The current code is simple, readable, and explicit. What advantages does your version have?

Comment: @DanielWagner, it just avoids explicitly re-throwing the exception. You can also do it your way using `handle` to avoid the flip.

Answer (score 4):

You could write such a function using `hLookAhead` and catching `isEOFError`. However, you'll be mixing your IO with your parsing.

A more Haskellish solution is to define:

```
parseInts :: String -> [Int]
parseInts str = map read (words str)
```

and then use `parseInts` like this:

```
-- read an entire file and convert to a list of Ints
nums <- fmap parseInts getContents


-- read just a line and convert to a list of Ints
nums <- fmap parseInts getLine
```

To parse a file which looks like:

```
3 4
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3
```

(e.g. 3 = number of rows, 4 = number of columns), you have a bunch of options:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

main = do
  (nrows : ncols : _) <- fmap parseInts getLine
  rows <- replicateM nrows $ fmap parseInts getLine
```

or

```
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

main = do
  (nrows : ncols : rest) <- fmap parseInts getContents
  let rows = chunksOf ncols rest
```

or even:

```
main = do
  (nrows : ncols : _) <- fmap parseInts getLine
  forM_ [1..nrows] $ \i -> do
    row <- fmap parseInts getLine
    ... do something with row...
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any simple/obvious way to create a getInt I am missing?

No. There isn't one. You're looking for something along `scanf("%d")`, which ignores all leading spaces and does not change the buffer if there's not a digit. You need to look ahead in this case:

```
import Data.Char (isSpace, isDigit, digitToInt)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Control.Monad (when)
import System.IO (hGetChar, hLookAhead, Handle, stdin)

getInt :: IO (Maybe Int)
getInt = hGetInt stdin

hGetIntegral :: (Integral n) => Handle -> IO (Maybe n)
hGetIntegral h = do 
  hSkipSpace h
  digits <- hGetDigits h
  return $ case digits of
    [] -> Nothing
    xs -> Just $ foldl' (\x a -> 10 * a + x) 0 . map digitToInt $ xs

hGetDigits :: Handle -> IO [Char]
hGetDigits h = do
  la <- hLookAhead h
  if isDigit la then hGetChar h >> fmap (la:) (hGetDigits h)
                else return []

hSkipSpace :: Handle -> IO ()
hSkipSpace h = do
  la <- hLookAhead h
  when (isSpace la) $ hGetChar h >> hSkipSpace h
```

Comment: By the way, `withCString "%d" $ \str -> with 0 $ \i -> c_scanf str i >> peek i` will provide the same behaviour as `scanf("%d", %i)`. But that's just for fun and shouldn't be mixed with other Haskell functions.

Comment: Nice use of `hLookAhead`. Maybe we should also check for `isEOF`?

Answer (score 0):

```
readInt :: [Char] -> Maybe Int
readInt [] = Nothing
readInt str = case reads str :: [(Int, String)] of
    [(x ,"")] -> (Just x)
    _ -> Nothing

getInt :: IO (Maybe Int)
getInt = do
    nums <- getLine
    return (readInt nums)
```

here you go , you can take the maybe out if need to , a well place just or by modyfying it

, aller bon courage